# how to do validation for file MIME type using with javascript in jsp

Tags: javascript

**how to do validation for file MIME type using with javascript in jsp. Kindly suggest on same. Whether we can do in client side validation or server side validation .**

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the validation it depends. If you allow any user to upload a file then the validation should definately happen server side. If the file upload is done from a CMS where only a couple of trusted users have access then you could also rely on a client-side validation(although I would still go with server side).

Now, in order to check the uploaded file's MIME type it should be fairly easy. You can use the following:

```
$fileInfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$fileType = finfo_file($fileInfo, $file);
finfo_close($fileInfo);
```